# Electron Application toolbar automation using selenium python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, electron

Is it  possible to automate the tool bar options like File. Edit, View , Window and Help options using Selenium webdriver with python?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium webdriver can only be used for Web GUI Automation. Try using python module like pywinauto or Microsoft specific WinAppDriver for GUI Automation